# Button.MouseMove event in WPF always has e.LeftMouse with status Released

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to start a drag and drop on a Button control in WPF. I am using Button because I also want to handle click event.

Adding a Button in XAML and handling the MouseMove event always has `e.LeftMouse` equal to `MouseButtonState.Released`.

```
<Button MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"/>
```

In the following handler implementation the exception is never thrown.

```
private void Button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        throw new Exception("It works!");
}
```

I noticed the same is true for any control I place inside a Button and try to process MouseMove event.

How do I handle drag and drop from a Button control or any other control inside a button in WPF?

EDIT - Solution based on mm8's answer

The updated XAML is:

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown"
        PreviewMouseUp="Button_PreviewMouseUp"
        PreviewMouseMove="Button_PreviewMouseMove">
</Button>
```

The updated handler code:

```
Point startPosition;
double delta = 10;
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    startPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this);

    if ((currentPosition - startPosition).Length < delta)
        throw new Exception("MouseClick");
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
    double currentDelta = (currentPosition - startPosition).Length;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && currentDelta >= delta)
        throw new Exception("DragAndDrop");
}
```

Comment: No, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event instead of `Click`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //handle click here...

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="Button_Click" MouseMove="Button_MouseMove"/>
```

Comment: That triggers the Exception, but Click event no longer works.

Comment: What do you mean by no longer works? You shouldn't handle `Click` but `PreviewMouseDown`. And this does get raised.

Comment: I think I could use a combination with PreviewMouseUp and put my click code there. On PreviewMouseDown I record the position and in PreviewMouseUp I check if the distance is great enough to handle my click code. I don't want to handle click code and MouseMove at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you just put your "click code" in `PreviewMouseDown` as per my working example?

Comment: I don't want to handle the click code if I move mouse after I pressed left button. Your code is helpful. I am working on a solution.

Comment: I have added the final solution as an edit to my question.